# Fedora Github I can't use git clone pull or push

Tags: github, networking, ssh, fedora

I am new at Fedora. I love that this distro recognize every device easily but I am struggling a lot with git github.

First it was my laptop. When I connect through my mobile data modem, It works, but when is connected through my wifi at home:

```
`ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out`
```

Now I installed Fedora on my PC and it's not working either.

On Debian is working, On windows is working.

I disabled the firewall, and nothing happend.
I contacted github and we tried using https instead of ssh and nothing
I contacted my provider and They said they would try something but they weren't helpful either.

Comment: If it works with one network connection but not with another, I would start investigating that network. You don't have a firewall of some kind in the router blocking outgoing port 22, do you? Is it correct that Debian and Windows works using the same wifi?

Comment: Thank you por commenting. It is correct, debian and windows with the same wifi, and LAN connection, work perfectly fine with port 22.

Fedora + other routers modem, works perfectly fine with port 22.

The problem is when Fedora is working with my router (LAN or WIFI) somehow, together, they block the SSH, HTTP connection with github, EC2 instances or other important things.